# How can I implement Network and Serial communication components in my WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

I'm looking for less technical and more conceptual answers on this one.

I am looking to build a WPF application using .NET 4.5 for controlling a rover, (glorified RC Car).  Here is the intended functionality:

- The application and rover will communicate wirelessly by sending and receiving strings - JSON over TCP Socket.
- The GUI will display multiple video feeds via RTSP.
- A control panel - custom hardware - will connect to the computer via USB and these signals will be converted to JSON before being sent over the TCP connection and providing movement instructions.
- The GUI will need to update to reflect the state of the control panel as well as the state of the rover based on data received.

I'm not sure which technologies to use to implement this, but from my research, BackgroundWorkers or Threads, and Asynchronous techniques would be things to look into.  Which of these seems like a good route to take?  Also, should I use TCP Sockets directly in the application or should/could I use WCF to provide this data?

Any wisdom on this would be great.  Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here was the final implementation used and boy did it workout great:

- Everything fell into place around using the **MVVM** pattern.

  - There were Views for the control panel and the networking component which each had a corresponding ViewModel that handled the background operations.
- **Updating the UI** was done via **databinding**, not the Dispatcher.
- **Wireless Communication** was done **Asynchronously (async/await) via [TCPListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx)** along with the use of **[Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)**.
- **Serial Port Communication** was done **Asynchronously via [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx)** and **Tasks**.
- Used [ModernUI](http://mui.codeplex.com/) for interface.
- Used [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) for the JSON parsing.

[Here is a link to the project](https://github.com/tjm6f4/MRDT-GUI).  It was done over the course of a month so it isn't the prettiest code.  I have refined my practices a lot this summer so I'm excited to work on a refactored version that should be completed next year.

Comment: Are you programming the rover yourself? In that case what technologies are used?

Comment: No, other programmers are doing it BUT essentially the rover-side is a raspberry pi utilized with Python.  The signals that the raspberry pi receives from the micro-controllers on the rover are sent via TCP to the GUI via wireless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using .NET 4.5 you dont need to use Threads and background workers for your project. you dont need to take care of all of your threads. As WPF's [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) is a very powerful tool for handling UI from other threads.

- For TCP Communication i would suggest you to use [TCP Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) and [TCP Listner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) with Async Callbacks. and use Dispatcher for Updating your UI.
- For Displaying Cameras over RTSP, Use [VLC.Net](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet) an Open source wrapper for VLC library good for handling many real time video protocols.
- Use Tasks instead of Threads, set their priority according to your requirement.

You don't need WCF for your application.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell (I'm no expert), MS's philosophy these days is to use asynchronous I/O, thread pool tasks for lengthy compute operations, and have a single main thread of execution for the main part of the application. That main thread drives the GUI and commissions the async I/O and thread pool tasks as and when required.

So for your application that would mean receiving messages asynchronously, and initiating a task on the thread pool to process the message, and finally displaying the results on the GUI when the task completes. It will end up looking like a single threaded event loop application. The async I/O and thread pool tasks do in fact use threads, its just they're hidden from you in an as convenient a way as possible.

I've tried (once) bucking this philosophy with my own separate thread handling all my I/O and an internal pipe connection to my main thread to tell it what's happening. I made it work, but it was really, really hard work. For example, I found it impossible to cancel a blocking network or pipe I/O operation in advance of its timeout (any thoughts from anyone out there more familiar with Win32 and .NET?). I was only trying to do that because there's no true equivalent to select() in Windows; the one that *is* there doesn't work with anything other than sockets... In case anyone is wondering 'why of why oh why?', I was re-implmenting an application originally written for Unix and naively didn't want to change the architecture.

Next time (if there is one) I'll stick to MS's approach.

==EDIT==

Since then, I have integrated WPF and ZeroMQ. Basically it means having two parallel event loops - WPF's running along side a thread handling ZerMQ Polling. The latter makes BeginInvoke() calls back to the WPF event loop to get things done on the GUI. This isn't as slick as WPF's event loop also handling ZeroMQ sockets directly (the equivalent can be done in other GUIs on *nix that can incorporate sockets / file descriptors as sources of events), but it'll do.